# Update state on successful update with code push

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm using code-push to update my react-native app. I don't want to upload it to App Store every time if I make an update, I want to push it directly to the users device.

It works fine, the app is updated but I'm trying to show an notification if the updated is successful.

In the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/api-js.md#codepushsync) they are doing it as follows:

```
codePush.sync({ updateDialog: true },
  (status) => {
      switch (status) {
          case codePush.SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE:
              // Show "downloading" modal
              break;
          case codePush.SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE:
              // Hide "downloading" modal
              break;
      }
  },
  ({ receivedBytes, totalBytes, }) => {
    /* Update download modal progress */
  }
);
```

I'm trying to update the state if the update is successful and show the modal, with an button to hide it on click. Thus my code is as follows:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            status: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        codePush.sync({
                updateDialog: true,
                installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
            }, (status) => {
                switch (status) {
                    case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
                        self.setState({modalVisible: true});
                        break;
                }
            },
            ({receivedBytes, totalBytes,}) => {
                /* Update download modal progress */
                self.setState({status: "Downloaded " + receivedBytes + " of " + totalBytes});
            }
        );
    }

    renderUpdateNotificationModal(){
        return (
            <Modal
                animationType={"slide"}
                transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
            >
                <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Updated</Text>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.setState({modalVisible: false})}}>
                            <Text>OK</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.renderUpdateNotificationModal()}
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    To get started, edit index.ios.js
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
                    Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
                </Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginTop: 15, color: "blue", textAlign: "center"}}>{this.state.status}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

But the problem is that the modal is shown for a few seconds and then it disappears, without clicking on the button.

As the state is set to true, and then after I few seconds to false in

```
case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
     self.setState({modalVisible: true});
     break;
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is there any flash screen after the update was installed? I think your app was restarted

Comment: @Jiro267 No. The modal is shown, and then after one second it disappears and I see the updated screen. The screen doesn't flash.

Comment: `installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE` this should be forcing an App restart according to https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/api-js.md#codepushoptions. Are you sure it's not restarting & initialising so quickly (the App is pretty minimal above!) that you are mistaking this for the modal closing and state resetting? Seems to point to this. Solution would be `codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESTART` or `codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME`

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of same promblem when trying to use Codepush in the loading page, My problem was that codePush's updateDialog was shown on the next screen.
because codePush.sync is a Promise function, you can use its 'then' feature, it will ensure doing your jobs in the right order.

[this demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/Examples/CodePushDemoApp/App.js) maybe be helpful if you want to use CodePush. You can change state of your component accordingly in codePushStatusDidChange().